# How to use characters in strings outside of the printable ASCII range?

Tags: arm, stm32, keil

I am trying to create a string with characters outside the ASCII printable range.  I am using an STM32 microcontroller using the [µVision IDE](http://www.keil.com/uvision/) with the Keil compiler.  The [documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125009236.htm) allows various escape sequences, including one for "ASCII code in hexadecimal."  When I just want one character there is no problem, but if I want to put other numbers in the same string after the character, I start getting issues.

This works.

```
char myString[10] = "\x06";//(It gives me 0x06,0x00,...,0x00)
```

This doesn't.  (It gives me 0x60

```
char myString[10] = "\x060";//(It gives me 0x60,0x00,...,0x00)
```

The more characters (0-F) in the same continuity that keep getting appended as hexadecimal digits of the same number (it will even throw a warning that it is out of range if the number gets too big).  Is there some way around this?  Might this be a compiler issue?

Comment: Related: ["When did C++ compilers start considering more than two hex digits in string literal character escapes?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784969/when-did-c-compilers-start-considering-more-than-two-hex-digits-in-string-lite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to terminate a hex escape sequence when followed by a character which is a hex digit, here is a way

```
"\x06""0"
```

Use two double-quotes.

Otherwise, a hex escape sequence will use up all consecutive hex digits that follow.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a string like that, you are specifying one character at a time. One character can only hold a value between 0 and 255. If you want to fill more bytes of your string, just specify more characters in the initializer:

```
char myString[4] = "\x06\x60\x44";
```

Note that unspecified characters are not guaranteed to be filled with 0's, although one 0 will be placed at the end of whatever you specify as the initializer:

```
char string2[8] = "test";
```

Five characters will be initialized, characters 6 through 7 might contain garbage.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that a string literal specifies one `char` at a time.  The OP did not say what _encoding_ he's using, but in some encodings, there can be more than one `char` per character.